# JQuery using object literal can't using $(this) always undefine on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

my problem after write as object literal as Jquery guide i can't using $(this) to access self on onlick="". please help correct my mistake.

my html

```
<a 
 data-id="<?=$product_id?>" 
 class="compare product-<?=$product_id?>" 
 onclick="(function(){compareInit.comGet();})()"
></a>
```

my js

```
   var compareInit = {

     /*  Store Item Compare  */
      comGet: function() {

          var e = $(this);
          var item_id = e.data('id');
          var item_image = e.find(".compare-hidden-image").val();
          var item_name = e.find(".compare-hidden-name").val();
          var count_item = $(".compare-item").length;
          var item_dialog = $(".compare-tray-dialog");
          var compare_button = $(".compare-tray-item");
          item_dialog.show();

          if (count_item > 1) {
          } else {
            $(".product-"+ item_id).css("color", "red").attr('onclick','');
          }
          if (count_item === 0) {
            compare_button.removeClass('activate').addClass('deactivate');
          } else {
            compare_button.removeClass('deactivate').addClass('activate');
          }
          $('.compare-remove').on("click", function() {
            var rem_id = $(this).data('id');
            $("." + rem_id).remove();
            $(".product-" + rem_id).css("color", "#fff").attr('onclick','(function(){compareInit.comGet();})()');
            compare_button.removeClass('activate').addClass('deactivate');
          });
      }
    };
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: you need to know how `this` works - quick fix for you ... change the onclick to `compareInit.comGet(this);` and change function `comGet` to `function (a) { var e = $(a); ...`

Comment: @JaromandaX it work now thz alot. this would be great to know how to use object literal.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `this` identifier from the onclick event and then access it under a name other than `this`  such as `elem`  as a parameter of your function.

```js
var compareInit = {

  /*  Store Item Compare  */
  comGet: function(elem) {
    console.log("working");
    var e = $(elem);
    var item_id = e.data('id');
    var item_image = e.find(".compare-hidden-image").val();
    var item_name = e.find(".compare-hidden-name").val();
    var count_item = $(".compare-item").length;
    var item_dialog = $(".compare-tray-dialog");
    var compare_button = $(".compare-tray-item");
    item_dialog.show();

    if (count_item > 1) {} else {
      $(".product-" + item_id).css("color", "red").attr('onclick', '');
    }
    if (count_item === 0) {
      compare_button.removeClass('activate').addClass('deactivate');
    } else {
      compare_button.removeClass('deactivate').addClass('activate');
    }
    $('.compare-remove').on("click", function() {
      var rem_id = $(this).data('id');
      $("." + rem_id).remove();
      $(".product-" + rem_id).css("color", "#fff").attr('onclick', '(function(){compareInit.comGet();})()');
      compare_button.removeClass('activate').addClass('deactivate');
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-id="3636" class="compare product-3636" onclick="compareInit.comGet(this)">Testing</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** apply the `this` inside the onclick function .If you apply this in object function its get the data from that object only

```js
var compareInit ={
    comGet : function(that){
                              console.log(that.innerHTML)
                            }
                  }
```

```html
<a  onclick="compareInit.comGet(this)">hello</a>
```

**Alternate:**

If get the `this` from whole object try with return like below .its like a jquery object `$(element).html()`

```js
var compareInit = function(that){
     return {
     comGet : function(){
                          console.log(that.innerHTML)
                        }
            }
     }
```

```html
<a  onclick="compareInit(this).comGet()">hello</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass-on the your required DOM element's `this` reference as follows:

`onclick="(function(){compareInit.comGet();})()"`; here you are invoking an anonymous function without passing anything to it. So there inside it `this` reference means that anonymous function itself. To achieve your goal you need to pass DOM reference as follows:

```js
var compareInit = {

  /*  Store Item Compare  */
  comGet: function(thisRef) {
  alert($(thisRef).text());
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" onclick="(function(thisRef){compareInit.comGet(thisRef);})(this)">Click Me!</div>
```